# How to insert whole html page (<html> tag) in ckeditor?

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to add a full html page into ckeditor for some editing via js.

Specifically, I execute the command

```
oEditor.insertHtml("<html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body><div>hello</div></body></html>");
```

But the result I get is the following:

```
<p>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
    </html>
</p>
<p>
    <title></title>
</p>
<div>
    hello</div>
```

The mode I use is:

```
config.fullPage = true
```

I tried also with fullPage = false, but not success.

Is there any way to insert to ckeditor a full html page?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The insert* methods append the data to the editor contents, but if you want to replace the whole content then you must use [setData](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setData).

Comment: Thanks! I 'll try it and come back to you!